# Social force model parameters in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to develope an Evacuation model in AnyLogic using pedestrian library. AnyLogic states that pedestrians movement is according to social force model but I couldn't find any documentary that explain this logic. I want to know is there any specific block or setting in this library which belongs to social force model parameters and give the accessibility to modify its parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the Pedestrian library uses a social-forces (physics-based) model underneath, it also uses 'custom' agent-based logic on top (e.g., to enable the social distancing functionality) and there is no explicit access to parameters of the underlying theoretical model.

You have to treat it as a 'black box', and you can only indirectly change some aspects of the behaviour by changing things such as ped diameter, comfortable speed, desired social distance, etc. (plus of course by building in explicit behaviour into the Ped library process flow). All the AnyLogic libraries work like this. You can also add your own custom (agent-based) behaviour on top; e.g., have pedestrians periodically 'scanning' for things and changing their behaviour (typically via conditional paths in the process flow) accordingly.