# How to set the parameters to change the wayfinding strategy of pedestrian in Anylogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to develop an agent model to simulate the evacuation scenarios in AnyLogic. I want to change some parameters to custom the wayfinding strategies of the pedestrian. But I couldn't find any description of the logic of the pedestrians movement and couldn't find a way to change the parameters. Does anyone know what can I do to modify the pedestrians movement model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Social force model parameters in AnyLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763695/social-force-model-parameters-in-anylogic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very little you can do, it is a black-box model working in the background. The help has some light details of how it works.

You can only adjust the environment to influence path-finding for pedestrians (close areas...).

Lastly, the "Ped settings" object has some light ways to adjust behavior:
[image]

If you need more than that, either create your own pedestrian agent type with 100% custom pathfinding capabilities (not trivial) or revert to tailored pedestrian-modelling tools

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I should try to create the own pedestrian agent type. But what should I do to custom the pathfinding strategies? Could you please give me some tips?

Comment: Not really, you'd need to research how pedestrian path-finding works. It is an entire research area with 100s of approaches and research papers... Human behavior is not trivial